# bootstrap tooltip causing screen resizing when triggered on hover

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, tooltip

Im trying to implement a tooltip on an element on my webpage,

data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="This is my tooltip text"

the problem is when i hover over the element, the tooltip first flashes on the bottom of the page, this causes it to resize the page and all my elements to jump and its very disconcerting.

The tooltip behaves properly once fully loaded, I was just wondering if there is a way to stop it from flashing at the bottom when i initially hover over the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue and I solved it like this:

```
$('body').tooltip({
    selector: '[rel=tooltip]',
    placement: 'auto',
    fallbackPlacement: 'flip',
    container: 'body'
});
```

The `container: body` part makes the parent element the body, which removed flickering for me.

Comment: Thanks, this lead me to the answer i was looking for.